# shopping cart rules magento 2.2.1

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, magento-2.2.1

I have done below steps to Set up a buy x Get y free on Shopping cart rules

1st. Go to Marketing > Cart prices rules

2nd. Click on Add new rule

3rd. Define a name, a short descritpion, select website and customer groups

4th. Define if your promotion require a coupon to be activated or not

5th. Define a period

6th. Conditions : nothing to set up here

7th. ACTIONS :

```
Select "Buy x Get Y free"

Discount amount put "1" (that means 1 prodcut free)

Maximum qty discount apply : Select how many times in the order this promotions can be applied

Discount qty : Put "2" for a Buy 2 get 1 Free
```

But I couldn't see the discount on cart page order summary section.

Kindly help me with this issue.

I have done cache,reindex,upgrade..

Comment: have you made coupon?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra no..

Comment: you have to add 3 items at cart then you get a discount off one item.

Comment: Just now i found out it is applicable when we add same product with quantity 4 then discount is applied

Comment: @AmitBera is there any extension or code to apply this condition for different product

Comment: free extension .Can be use.

Comment: could you suggest me the extension..